# How to force excel not to drop rows when opening csv-file?

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-excel

**Background:**

We have a web application where the user can export orders in csv-format. For users with Microsoft Excel installed it's the default program. They simply click 'Open' after the file is downloaded. Users mainly use Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome. No difference in behaviour.

**The problem:**

If the user just open the csv-file (from browser or explorer) the file is opened by Excel and data is loaded automagically. But sometimes rows are just missing. Gone. No exception, no message, nothing.

The data *is* there, if you open the file with notepad you'll see it.

(I suspect it has something to do with special chars, quotes, commas etc but I can't find a root cause for this)

**How to make it work:**

If you save the file to disk, open excel and selects `File -> Open -> Format: Textfiles (*.prn, *.txt, *.csv, *.skv) -> Open` excel will launch a import wizard and everything will work perfectly.

**Is there anything I can do with the export-file to either force the Import Wizard or just tell Excel not to exclude our critical order information without warning?**

Comment: How about using the .txt extension?

Comment: What content type are you sending? Can you post an example of a working and a missing line?

Comment: What version of excel is it? And how many lines are in the native text file? If it is excel 2003 and you have more than ~32000 lines they'll get dropped.

Comment: It's Excel 2010 and around 2k-5k lines. See my answer below, I found the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found the cause of this. It seems to be due to regional settings as described in [this post](http://hotware.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/trouble-with-opening-csv-files-with-excel-the-comma-and-semicolon-issue-in-excel-due-to-regional-settings-for-europe/) and sugesstions from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/180964/how-to-open-semicolon-delimited-csv-files-in-us-version-of-excel)

I solved it by **wrapping all fields** except numbers **with quotes** and now it works just fine.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for saving me a headache :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use a consistent delimiter scheme across all lines in the file. For example, check if you have both \n and \r\n sequences as line delimiters.